# Why "Parsing Select and Expand failed" error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing an app that will call various Microsoft Graph API. What could explain the above error with this API call?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName$filter=accountEnabled eq true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't post a comment, so I try it with an answer. :)

You missed a "&" in your URL before $filter.
You have to concat the diffrent options with "&".

Try it with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName&$filter=accountEnabled eq true
```

Btw. this call is available in "v1.0". Maybe you can change this as well.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName&$filter=accountEnabled eq true
```

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if this was the solution for your problem. :)